# Rotation disabled when testing mobile in flash builder

Tags: mobile, flash-builder, screen-rotation

For some unknown reason, the two rotation options in the menu are disabled when I am testing mobile application in Flash Builder's emulator (AIR SDK is 3.5). AutoOrients is set to true, and when compiled and tested on the device it works as intended. What is weirder, the rotation used to work perfectly a couple of times before (but at the start it didn't work either) but I don't think I've changed anything that could potentially change this behaviour.

Did you experience such a situation, and if yes, how did you make the rotation work again?

Comment: Might a AIR 3.5 issue. Have you experienced this issue with the stable 3.4 release as well?

Comment: Yes, I've experienced it with previous SDK versions too, and it also was pretty random there - first didn't work but then, one time, it started to behave correctly.

Comment: Do you limit the orientation somehow to just portrait or landscape? I've got it that way and the buttons are disabled, too. Maybe FB 4.6 can't handle the orientation restriction.

Comment: Nope, not disabled or limited in any way, when tested on iPad the rotation works perfectly. Maybe it's indeed somehow related to SDK 3.5, I'll download latest update and see if it helps.